# Error 401"Context creation failed: Error: Unauthorised:" when running a Postman tests from Jenkins. Why?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, postman

I have a Postman tests that passes OK in my local running via newman or postman runner.
The test reads some values from a environment file and calls an API with certain headers.
[image]

But when i run the same test via newman / Jenkins, this throws in the console with an authorization error 401:
[image]

```html
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Context creation failed: Error: Unauthorised",
      "extensions": {
        "code": 401
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

why is this happening? Does Jenkins have problems when writing or reading values from environment files? the error indicates 401 authentication but it is very strange, I'm seeing the headers im passing in the Jenkins console and they look all good, same as when i run it from my local.
[image]